# How information security/cyber security evolved for a Novice End user in the Last 10 Years

Tags: privacy, attack-prevention, cyber-warfare, end-user, consumer-protection

- The main point to note is the type of laws that protect the users.
  Its main focus is

  My points of discussion include 1) Challenges faced in Cyber-security. 2) Evolution of cyber security over the last 10 years 3) How to stay protected online : Education as a solution. 5) number of attacks facing end users. 6) types of laws to be implemented. There not necessarily in correct order but they shed light on what i want to discuss. Any extra input or thoughts would be appreciated. I am brainstorming as truly speaking quantifying the last 10 years is quite a huge task.

These are the questions that i intend to research on.
-How has cyber-security laws evolved for the novice Users.
– What are ways of ensuring end-users are protected. 
- What type of future can be expected as cyber laws evolve to protect the end users as malware attacks are on the rise?

Brainstorming for more.

Comment: What jurisdiction are you wanting to know about?

Comment: Western Australia does not currently have a proper cyber security law. I would like to observe or research around the world and see how developing countries are adapting to the laws and how the non-developing countries are being affected.

Comment: http://www.aic.gov.au/publications/current%20series/htcb/1-20/htcb005.html suggests that section 440A of the Criminal Code contains to computer crime, it seems that it is like the computer misuse act (1990) in the uk which I believe is based on an EU Directive so all EU countries should have a comparative law

Comment: Wow thanks people, im glad to have joined this site. Cybersecurity laws are constantly changing around the world and since Western Australia does not have the proper laws to protect end users who are mostly uneducated on principalities of proper online etiquette manner. What kind of issues would be advisable to discuss in order to explain how western australia should adapt to the every changing world in terms of cyber laws to protect the end users?

Comment: Just to add or explain a bit further, My points of discussion include         1) Challenges faced in Cyber-security. 2) Evolution of cybersecurity over the last 10 years 3) How to stay protected online : Education as a solution. 5) number of attacks facing end users. 6) types of laws to be implemented. There not necessarily in correct order but they shed light on what i want to discuss. Any extra input or thoughts would be appreciated. I am brainstorming as truly speaking quantifying the last 10 years is quite a huge task. Thanks always.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hard to answer and a bit non-objective (Q3 isn't).

First: every country has its own laws, so it depends on the countries.

> Q1 - How has cyber-security laws evolved for the novice Users.

For the novice users, well i don't understand what you're really asking about. But laws has not changed so much for novice users, it's all about cyber security, that involves mostly cyber-crimes.

Novices are more protected against cyber-crimes by laws and security professionals in police and intelligence departments.

The evolution of security laws in the last 10 years is as hard to explain and tell as summarizing the last 10 million years of earth. Too many things have happenned.

> Q2 – What are ways of ensuring end-users are protected.

The end-users protection has been evolving, few things i could enumerate:

- Most countries have data-protection laws.
- Most countries have laws to punish cyber scams.
- Most countries have laws against cyber crimes (thefts, bullying, ...)

As i've said the evolution of cyber-security laws in last ten years, has been so huge to tell in few words. And it's not about security experts or computer engineers competence, but by lawers and similar.

> Q3 – What type of future can be expected as cyber laws evolve to
>   protect the end users as malware attacks are on the rise?

This is the question in which everybody can tell whatever is imagined by our minds.

Malware attacks protection is not about laws, there are still laws to punish any kind of cyber delinquency, but about cyber-cops (security expert departments in police), and many other security experts.

Laws will keep evolving as in any other matter, but at the computer and security evolving speed.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks mate, you do give a good point about how it is not easy to quantify the last 10 years in cyber laws. The rise of technology can be attributed to that because there are new methods to perform attacks and even not enough laws to protect them. There is always a loop hole somewhere used to achieve what one wants. I'm curious though why people would downvote this question, there is no cyber security section to post it and information security is the closest but still instead of offering their two cents, they downvote it and prevent someone from learning a new concept. Thanks for your input